# unshiftObject method is not working in ember

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the array of Objects and want to concat only the list property of all objects and create a new array. So I have a "combinedList" getter in the below code to combine the list if array length is greater than 1 else just return the 1st items list property. This returned array will be used in the template file to display. If any new item is added, the addComment function will be called with the newly added item and push that to the "combinedList" array.

The problem here is, if the objArr length is less than 1, the newItem is pushed to the "combineList". But, if it is greater than 1, newItem is not pushed to the "combinedList" array.

Can anyone please help me to figure out the cause for this issue?

```
export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  objArr = [ {id:1, list:[1,2,3]}, {id:2, list:[3,4]} ];

  get combinedList() {
    if (this.objArr.length > 1) {
      let list = [];
      this.objArr.forEach((item) => {
        list.push(...item.list);
      });
      return list;
    }
    return this.objArr[0].list;
  }

  // Call this method when adding a new item
  addComment(newItem) {
    this.combinedList.unshiftObject(newItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `this.` in at least one place:  `if (this.objArr.length > 1)`.  Also, it kinda looks like you meant to do `list.push(...item.list);`  I'll call this either a typo or a facepalm.  (honest mistake though, but careless not to debug before posting on this site.)

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code.

Comment: Aren't computed properties intended to be read-only?  Adding an element to the `list = []` you returned (with `unshiftObject`) won't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: Wyck, there are no computed properties here

Comment: Folks should stop voting to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

Given this code:

```js
export default class YourComponent extends Component {
  objArr = [ {id:1, list:[1,2,3]}, {id:2, list:[3,4]} ];

  get combinedList() {
    if (this.objArr.length > 1) {
      let list = [];
      this.objArr.forEach((item) => {
        list.push(...item.list);
      });
      return list;
    }
    return this.objArr[0].list;
  }

  // Call this method when adding a new item
  addComment(newItem) {
    this.combinedList.unshiftObject(newItem);
  }
}
```

A couple things  will make your life easier:

1. *getters may not mutate data*

   - no violation here, so we're good
2. ℹ️ getters re-run every time they are called (they are like methods)

   - this means that each time `combinedList` is accessed, you could get a new `list` object.
3. `unshiftObject` is not a property on Array.prototype -- you may want `unshift`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift
4. methods must have a bound `this` (JavaScript goofiness)
5. if the UI is going to render combinedList in anyway, it needs to auto-tracking enabled

### Resolving #2

add a `@cached` on it so that it'll be a stable reference each time `combinedList` is accessed:

```js
import { cached } from '@glimmer/tracking';

// ...

@cached
get combinedList() {
  // ...  
}
```

### Resolving #3

```js
  addComment(newItem) {
    this.combinedList.unshift(newItem);
  }
```

### Resolving #4

```js
addComment = (newItem) => this.combinedList.unshift(newItem);
```

### Resolving #5

```js
import { TrackedArray } from 'tracked-built-ins';


// ...

  @cached
  get combinedList() {
    if (this.objArr.length > 1) {
      let list = new TrackedArray();
      this.objArr.forEach((item) => {
        list.push(...item.list);
      });
      return list;
    }
    return new TrackedArray(this.objArr[0].list);
  }
```

this will allow `unshift` to update the UI

Comment: This answer was correct, have a very similar situation and using ember-cached-decorator-polyfill and tracked-built-ins in my 3.28 app allowed me to use unshift (and push) correctly)